# Change text color based on background color?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I've a pretty minimalistic site, so I want to add details to it, like a hidden theme switching. But I don't want to tell the user that the theme can be changed, so I want to hide the text.

I've tried this:

```
var tausta = $(body).css("background-color");
$('.piiloteksti').css("color",tausta);
```

But it doesn't do anything. What would be the correct approach?

[A fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/HbAHS/4/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`if($('.piiloteksti').css("color",tausta);` is a **wrong** statement. Thats a syntax error! There shouldn't be any `if` here.

Either remove `if`

```
$('.piiloteksti').css("color",tausta);
```

or complete the `if` statement.

```
if($('.piiloteksti').css("color",tausta)){
 // some other code
}
```

Also `$(body)` does not refer to anything. Use either `$('body')` or `$(document.body)`

Comment: some kind of mistake I made writing it to the fiddle, updated my code. It doesn't work...

Comment: @ChristianNikkanen I have also tested in fiddle. See http://jsfiddle.net/HbAHS/6/

Answer (score 0):

The syntax of your the if statement was off a little.  Also, `body` must be made a String literal.

```
var tausta = $("body").css("background-color");
$('.piiloteksti').css("color", tausta);
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/HbAHS/8/

Comment: @StephanBönnemann How body can be undefined, as the site contents are within `<body></body>`?

Comment: @ChristianNikkanen because body should be a string literal

Comment: Yeah, I got the idea of it, but this isn't what I need. I want .piiloteksti elemements to have the color of the body ;)

Comment: ok thats easy, I will modify.  My answer has been updated to meet your requirements.  If there is anything you have a question about let me know and we can work through it.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I tried to modify CSS, and it works.

// javascript

```
var tausta = $('body').css("background-color");
if($('.piiloteksti').css("color") == tausta) {
   alert(tausta);
}
```

// css (test)

```
body{background-color:red;}
.piiloteksti{color:red;}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can hide the element with CSS

`.piiloteksti{display:none;}` [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HbAHS/9/)

OR if you think that would interfere with your layout then,

`.piiloteksti{visibility:hidden;}` [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HbAHS/11/)

Or you can just give transparent color to your `piiloteksti` elements

`.piiloteksti{color:transparent;}` [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HbAHS/10/)